# What does "Simultaneous Live View Up to 6 channels" imply for a IP Camera specification

Tags: camera, ip, channel, hikvision

I was looking at the specifications for Hikvision Camera DS-2CD1043G0E-I. It says

```
"Simultaneous Live View:  Up to 6 channels"
```

What does this imply? There is only one network port and only one IP address can be assigned to it. RTSP port can be configured though. How can a camera support up to 6 channels? My understanding is that the camera can feed into some middleware from where the same video stream can be sent to multiple channels. But having this done in the camera itself is not something that I understand. Can you explain?

Comment: Did you hit the wrong button? Weird that someone with so much reputation has posted such a wildly off topic question